# Packaging ruby gtk app

Tags: ruby, gtk, gtk3, gtk2, ruby-gnome2

What is the least headache technique to package a gtk2/gtk3 app built with ruby  for distribution as an executable, for windows, linux, macos?

I could not find any guides or helpers to resolve this for ruby gtk. Nor the ruby-gnome gem comes with a packager.

It is my understanding that gtk is cross-platform, so it should not be trivial to do this. Problem is I am unable to find anythin reliable to follow as an example and learn the steps.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same problem as you and I've put the question directly to the GTK3 developers.

here is [their answer](https://github.com/ruby-gnome/ruby-gnome/issues/1306).

Which means that if you choose to use GTK3 today with Ruby, you have to:

- Deliver MSYS2 and Ruby with your GEM.
- Deliver your gem and tell users to install themselves msys2 (with updates) and ruby and your gem with dependencies.

Comment: WSL1 and probably WSL2 work; it requires some knowledge how to use e. g. apt-get, and set export DISPLAY=:0 and use xming perhaps, but I am able to use all ruby-gtk parts on win10 that way. Even autostarting that works, e. g. start an ubuntu instance and upon login run some shell script via &. I am sure there are more ways for that but I am a bit of a windows noob. What I can, however had, say, is that you can leverage WSL just fine. I can run KDE konsole and ruby-gtk parts on win10 that way. It's almost a bit like linux (not the same; there are issues, but it sort of works).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the core developers of [ruby-gnome2](http://ruby-gnome2.osdn.jp/) are unconcerned about app distribution outside the Ruby community.

For example, Mr. Sutou, one of [the maintainers](http://ruby-gnome2.osdn.jp/hiki.cgi?Status) of ruby-gnome2, distributes his Ruby/Gtk presentation tool "[Rabbit](https://github.com/rabbit-shocker/rabbit)" only as a [Ruby Gem](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/09/ruby-gems-gemfiles-bundler/).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know of a new tool. But I am not sure how this is related to packaging Ruby/GTK apps as executables.

Comment: Ruby gem can packages excutables. Ruby users will install your tool just type `gem install foo`. But for those who don’t use ruby it may be difficult.

Comment: Not as a gem. As a .exe for windows, .deb for debian, .app for osx.

Comment: Probably there is no established easy way. Developers of ruby-gnome2 distribute their tools mainly by gem. You should develop convenient package method yourself to help others.

Comment: There is nothing wrong using rubygems. It simplified installation greatly, compared to the old setup.rb days. A problem with windows is that the dev-ecosystem is not as trivial to use for e. g. linux/OSX folks. But you can use WSL1 and WSL2 just fine - all my ruby-gtk code works there, and within that distribution you can do "gem install gtk2, then use these widgets (and mingx/xming whatever the name of it is; I am sure there may be wayland-related tools too eventually).